# Why is my router losing Internet connection when I connect my computer?

Tags: router, internet, ethernet, routing

When I connect my computer to the router (cable or wireless) the connection to the Internet is lost, and all other computers which are connected to the router don't have Internet. When I try to ping my router some packets are lost. When I disconnect the computer all other computers have Internet normally. I have set DHCP and I don't use static IP. Any solutions?

Comment: loose <> lose. The former means it wobbles or you set it free. The latter means you can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using VMWare or VirutalBox? If not properly configured, the DHCP server that those virtualization products provide can provide DHCP to the other computers / devices on your real network and causes the devices to send all requests to your computer rather than your router.

Otherwise, have you configured Internet Connection Sharing on the troublesome computer? That may also have a similar effect...

Answer (score 0):

This type of thing is often either a driver, or more likely, hardware.

Since you have connected with two different network cards, one without a wire, you can PROBABLY rule out those network cards and cables (assuming you unplug the wire when trying to connect wirelessly). You still have signs of a network card broadcasting garbage since it is interfering with other computers, and goes away when you unplug it. You might try another wired NIC. I would also see if you can connect your computer directly to your Internet connection, and see if it continues to happen. If not, you know the router is the issue.

At that point, you will probably need a new router, but you can at least try on more thing: Try copying your settings manually, updating the firmware and then resetting it to factory defaults to make sure that it is not just a corrupted configuration or corrupted firmware. Then test one last time. If it does not work, you can head to the store.